# html 5 audio download button not showing in iphone and mac

Tags: javascript, php, html

In my case i want to give feasibility to user download mp3 file and it's good working in google crome, but in safari audio tag is working fine but download option is not showing.

```
html code

<audio controls>
 <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
 <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
 Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: Your tag starts with <audio controls> and end with </audio> . are you sure you are not doing anything wrong?

Comment: i think control is attribute no need to write in closing tag

Comment: `controls` is indeed an attribute for the `<audio>` tag. Could be a chrome specific thing to download the audio file, I don't get to download on Firefox either. Edit: I get the option to "Save Audio As..." when right-clicking the `<audio>` element (in Firefox)

Comment: or i give directly download button

Answer (score -1):

On Safari 15.3 after fiddling a bit I discovered an option that right-clicking on the middle section of the HTML5 element offers you the menu with action "Download Video as...".

Despite the label, it downloads the audio source of the HTML5 element fine. Note that I tested it only for a wavefile.

[image]